# Interpret Results From ANOVA of Transformed Data

Tags: anova, data-transformation

*Similar questions are out there, but they do not answer my question in particular, so I decided to continue with asking mine*

In a simple experiment, we took different material balls of similar radius (Golf ball, Ping Pong ball, Styrofoam ball) and at 3 different heights on a wooden board used as a ramp (4 inches, 8 inches, 12 inches), we rolled them across different surfaces (Kitchen Tile, Carpet, and Sand Paper) to see which factors had an effect on how far the ball rolled.

This is a factorial experiment with three factors with three levels for each factor. **The response variable is the Distance rolled (in inches)**

After performing the experiment for the 27 different combinations (with 3 replicates) I ran the ANOVA and the output was as follows:

```
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Height             2   7277    3638 131.242  < 2e-16 ***
Ball               2  49020   24510 884.142  < 2e-16 ***
Floor              2  24337   12168 438.946  < 2e-16 ***
Height:Ball        4   3810     953  34.360 2.95e-14 ***
Height:Floor       4    889     222   8.017 3.78e-05 ***
Ball:Floor         4  16249    4062 146.538  < 2e-16 ***
Height:Ball:Floor  8   1288     161   5.806 2.40e-05 ***
Residuals         54   1497      28                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, looking at the diagnostic plots, the residual plot showed violation of the assumption of residuals having constant variance.

[image]

So I decided to use a <strike>{**log transformation**}</strike> **square root transformation** on the data

After creating the model for the transformed data, first I noticed that the transformation had helped with the violated assumption.

[image]

Next I ran an ANOVA, and the new output looks as follows:

```
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)    
Height             2  32.23   16.12  166.437  < 2e-16 ***
Ball               2 256.71  128.35 1325.578  < 2e-16 ***
Floor              2 106.83   53.41  551.632  < 2e-16 ***
Height:Ball        4   8.38    2.10   21.644 1.06e-10 ***
Height:Floor       4   0.79    0.20    2.039    0.102    
Ball:Floor         4  42.35   10.59  109.355  < 2e-16 ***
Height:Ball:Floor  8   1.99    0.25    2.565    0.019 *  
Residuals         54   5.23    0.10                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The `Height:Floor` interaction is no longer significant.

**Questions**

- Does this mean that the violated assumption in the model of the original data had caused the ANOVA to incorrectly say that `Height:Floor` had a significant interaction effect when in reality there doesn't appear to be one?
- When I run a Tukey's Test on the transformed data model, do these comparisons relate to the original data? (e.g. if there is a significant difference between the means of `high:golf:carpet` and `low:golf:carpet` in the Tukey's Test in the transformed data, can I say that there is also a significant difference in the means of these two in the original data?)
- Are any conclusions I make from transformed data applicable to the original data set? Does being significant in the transformed model mean that it is also significant in the original model (and thus means significant in a real world scenario of rolling down a ramp?)

Comment: Your plots strongly suggest using the *square root* of the distance rather than its logarithm as the response variable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! After using the new transformation (with square root now rather than log) my output has different p-values but as far as significance goes, the `Height:Floor` interaction is still insignificant while all other effects are. My questions at the bottom still apply here. (I will edit and replace the results from log with square root)

Comment: I agree your questions still apply (that's why I upvoted your post originally).

Comment: edit: I know that using a log transformation will allow me to compare the geometric means (through back transformation) among the different groups but does the square root transformation make for any similar comparisons?